# Topology on $\mathbb{I}$

Tags: general-topology, compactness, equivalence-relations, connectedness, irrational-numbers

Let $\mathbb{I} = \mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$ be the set of irrational numbers. Define the equivalence relation $\sim$ on $\mathbb{I}$  such, that $\forall x,y\in\mathbb{I}:\big((x\sim y) \Leftrightarrow (x - y \in \mathbb{Q})\big)$. Is $\mathbb{I}/{\sim}$ either compact, connected, Hausdorff?

As I understand it is not Hausdorff, because any neighborhood of point $x$ in $\mathbb{I}$  contains some points which are located on enough small rational distance from $x$. Therefore any neighborhood of $[x]_{\sim}$ is intersecting with the neighborhood of some other points.

The space $\mathbb{I}$ itself with induced topology is not connected or compact, however it does not entail that $\mathbb{I}/{\sim}$ is not compact or connected.

I’ve tried to work with quotient metric, but it is trivial here. So i’m stuck a little bit.

Comment: Share your thoughts and work on this. Don’t just post a (homework) problem with no effort.

Comment: If $x, y \in \Bbb I$, Can you find a neighborhood of $x$ that does not contain a point equivalent to $y$?

Comment: @paul-sinclair  No you can’t. This is what I’m stating in the question. That is why $\mathbb{I}/\sim$ is not Hausdorff.

Comment: You need to think harder about what that means for the topology of $\Bbb I/\sim$. there is more than "not Hausdorff" to be found in the consequences.

Answer (score 1):

On connectedness and compactness:

Consider any two open sets ($\mathbb{I}$-wise) $X_{1},X_{2}\in \mathbb{I}$. Let
\begin{equation}
q: \mathbb{I}\to\mathbb{I}/{\sim}
\end{equation}
be a quotient map. Note, that there always exist such $x_{1}\in X_{1}$ and $x_{2}\in X_{2}$, that $x_{1} - x_{2}\in\mathbb{Q}\Rightarrow x_{1}\sim x_{2}$. Then $q(X_{1})\cap q(X_{2})\ne 0$. That means that $\mathbb{I}$ could not be represented as two open disjoint sets and, therefore, $\mathbb{I}/{\sim}$ is (topologically) connected (by definition).

Moreover note that the same argument tells us that the representatives of all of the equivalency classes $[x]_{\sim}$ are contained in any arbitrary small interval of $\mathbb{R}$. That entails that the quotient topology  on $\mathbb{I}/{\sim} $ is indiscrete. And therefore all of the open coverings of $\mathbb{I}/{\sim} $ are finite, which of course mean that $\mathbb{I}/{\sim}$ is compact.